# Return 0 for count when no data present for that month

Tags: sql

I am trying to get back 12 rows, 1 for each month from this month back.
I am using this to populate a graph, but as no data for early last year, the graph shows July's data as January's (as is first row of data).

[Image of the current graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NI0ZJ.jpg)

As you can see in this image, the blue line ends in september. That is actually meant to be February's data. And March (first data point), is actually July's data

Because of this, I need to be able to return COUNT as 0 if there is no data for that month.

I have created a ref_months table which holds 12 records, each one a month Jan-Dec.

I have the following query:

```
SELECT
    appointment.time AS appointmentdatetime,
    ref_months.text AS ref_month_text,
    ref_months.month AS ref_month_int,
    YEAR(TIME) AS appointmentyear,
    COUNT(appointment.id) AS COUNT
FROM
    appointment
RIGHT OUTER JOIN ref_months ON ref_months.month = MONTH(appointment.time)
WHERE
    appointment.time >= DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL - 12 MONTH)
GROUP BY
    ref_months.month
ORDER BY
    appointmentyear ASC,
    ref_month_int ASC
```

This currently returns:

```
+---------------------+----------------+------------------+--------------------+-------+--+
| appointmentdatetime | ref_month_text | ref_month_int    | appointmentyear    | COUNT |  |
+---------------------+----------------+------------------+--------------------+-------+--+
| 2019-07-27 13:00:00 | July           |                7 |               2019 |     1 |  |
| 2019-08-26 13:00:00 | August         |                8 |               2019 |     2 |  |
| 2019-09-06 13:00:00 | September      |                9 |               2019 |     8 |  |
| 2019-10-22 12:00:00 | October        |               10 |               2019 |     9 |  |
| 2019-11-21 12:00:00 | November       |               11 |               2019 |    15 |  |
| 2019-12-27 11:00:00 | December       |               12 |               2019 |     2 |  |
| 2020-01-22 15:00:00 | January        |                1 |               2020 |     4 |  |
| 2020-02-12 09:00:00 | February       |                2 |               2020 |     1 |  |
+---------------------+----------------+------------------+--------------------+-------+--+
```

What I need to return is this (last 12 months, if no data, show count as 0):

```
+---------------------+----------------+------------------+--------------------+-------+--+
| appointmentdatetime | ref_month_text | ref_month_int    | appointmentyear    | COUNT |  |
+---------------------+----------------+------------------+--------------------+-------+--+
| NULL                | March          |                3 |               NULL |     0 |  |
| NULL                | April          |                4 |               NULL |     0 |  |
| NULL                | May            |                5 |               NULL |     0 |  |
| NULL                | June           |                6 |               NULL |     0 |  |
| 2019-07-27 15:00:00 | July           |                7 |               2019 |     1 |  |
| 2019-08-26 13:00:00 | August         |                8 |               2019 |     2 |  |
| 2019-09-06 13:00:00 | September      |                9 |               2019 |     8 |  |
| 2019-10-22 12:00:00 | October        |               10 |               2019 |     9 |  |
| 2019-11-21 12:00:00 | November       |               11 |               2019 |    15 |  |
| 2019-12-27 11:00:00 | December       |               12 |               2019 |     2 |  |
| 2020-01-22 15:00:00 | January        |                1 |               2020 |     4 |  |
| 2020-02-12 09:00:00 | February       |                2 |               2020 |     1 |  |
+---------------------+----------------+------------------+--------------------+-------+--+
```

I have tried every variation of LEFT, RIGHT, INNER joins, and still not getting back empty rows.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0):

I strongly recommend `LEFT JOIN` and starting with the table where you want to keep everything.  Then, be very careful about what goes into the `WHERE` clause.

So, I think you want:

```
SELECT a.time AS appointmentdatetime,
       m.text AS ref_month_text,
       m.month AS ref_month_int,
       YEAR(TIME) AS appointmentyear,
       COUNT(a.id) AS COUNT
FROM ref_months m LEFT JOIN
     appointment a
     ON r.month = MONTH(a.time) AND
        a.time >= DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL - 12 MONTH)
GROUP BY m.month
ORDER BY appointmentyear ASC, ref_month_int ASC;
```

Your `WHERE` clause is undoing the outer join.  There are some other things I would note:

- Your `GROUP BY` does not match the unaggregated columns in the `SELECT`.  This will generate a syntax error in most databases, including the more recent versions of MySQL.
- The current month will be partially populated by this year and last year.  That seems strange to me.
- It is totally unclear why you want an arbitrary value of `a.time` in the result set.  This, in particular, is screaming for `MIN()`, `MAX()`, or `GROUP_CONCAT()`.
- `appointmentyear` will be `NULL` on the rows where there is no appointment.  That seems a bit weird.

If you want to address these, I would suggest asking a NEW question, with appropriate sample data, desired results, and explanation.

Comment: Thanks for the swift response!
I shall create a new question